# What is this calligraphy-like typeface called?

Tags: font-identification

I'm customizing the design of a receipt  and one of the font uses this image as a text

[image]

How could I write a word using that same style and font with corel draw 13?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

[Delphin Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/delphin-pro/) family looks pretty similar:

[image]